# Full calendar : how to display 'busy day' for days with events without displaying each event?

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I'm using jquery FullCalendar. Now I need a to display a smaller version of it.

I would like, in the monthView, to 'highlight' a day if it has events (but not display each event), and with qTip show the list of events for that day on mouse over.

Is there a way to achieve that ?
Thanks for help
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you could handle some of the events of the calendar... and apply a different CSS class to those busy days or even handle the drawing event yourself.

In the backend, you should return one event for the day that has several events. It should be a "dummy" event with a title "Busy" and the date.

[RenderEvent manually](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)

[EventRender, callback to handle the drawing of the events](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)